# Get PHP's tmp filename during upload

Tags: php, file-upload

Is it possible to get the uploading file `/tmp/name` before the file is uploaded.

The reason for this is that i need  to `echo` the actual uploading bytes every; may be 2 second interval before the file is uploaded completely.

I have managed to get the file `/tmp/name` and its file size but only after the upload is done.

Any help or ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: use something like dropzone or blueimp. If you want to reinvent the wheel, check this libraries code and make your own

Comment: The PHP script isn't started until the upload is complete. If you want to display a progress bar, you need to do it in the client with JavaScript.

Comment: @Barmar Hmm.., that may be a good idea

Comment: If you are using PHP 5.4 or above you could try something like this http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php - You may have to have some control over the server to set the correct values, but it is possible to see the uploaded bytes. Just use AJAX to read the current values in the session :)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a JQuery Function which will get triggered before the *actual submission* of your form happens.

**Suppose Your Form is like:**

```
<form id="form_test">
  //Your Input Fields
</form>
```

**What you can do is:**

```
$('#form_test').submit(function() {
    //You can get the values of each and every input field here
    //Get the file input value here
    return true; // return false to cancel form action
});
```